# Input method inside a Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I have some problem turning my Student Manager Program into GUI mode
The `Student` class hold some information of a student

```
public class Student {
    private String id,fullname,mark[],Subject,course[];
    private Time bday;
    private int n;
```

I have created a Jframe with text fields just as the properties of the `Student` class and an "Enter" button
I want when I click the button, a student to be imported into the list of `Student`s
But I'm still in confusion don't know whether I should put the `input()` method inside the Jframe as an ActionPerformed when the button is clicked or putting the Jframe inside the `input()` method of the `Student` class

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("ENTER");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String id = textField.getText();
                String name = textField_1.getText();
                String day1 = textField_2.getText();
                String month1 = textField_7.getText();
                String year1 = textField_8.getText();
                int day = Integer.valueOf(day1);
                int month = Integer.valueOf(month1);
                int year = Integer.valueOf(year1);
                Time bday = new Time(day,month,year);
                String email = textField_3.getText();
                String acc = textField_4.getText();
                String pass = textField_5.getText();
                String course1 = textField_6.getText();
                int coursen = Integer.valueOf(course1);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** put `input()` logic inside `JFrame` **nor** inside `Student` class (though it is not clear to me what do you want to do in `input()` method). Because (as I guess) `Student` is your model which should have proper instantiation methods (Constructors, Builders, e.t.c) and the `JFrame` is a mechanism which helps you to interact with user. In my opinion `JFrame` may have some kind of basic logic, for instance parsing DateTimes or Integers from text fields (just as your example. Also you should take care of parsing exceptions in this case), but in general it **should not** contain any logic. It **should be** used only for creating user-friendly UI/UX to facilitate user interaction with the program.
*Handling User Input* should be done in a separate class. By saying *"User Input Handling"* I mean **Verifying & Parsing** User Input as well as performing corresponding **actions on backend**. That class is some kind of Controller (MVC Pattern).

Lets assume your `Student` class has only 2 fields - **name & age.** Here is the possible code you can use:

```java
class StudentListController implements StudentAdderUIDelegate, StudentAdderBackendDelegte {
    private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    private StudentAdderUI ui;
    private StudentAdderBackend backend;

    public StudentListController() {
        ui = new StudentAdderUI(this);
        backend = new StudentAdderBackend(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void processStudent(String studentName, String studentAge) {
        // validate studentName
        // validate studentAge

        Student s = ...; // create Student object from studentName & studentAge
        studentList.add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void uiClosed() {
        // when user done adding students
        // then we can send the list to backend for processing
        backend.processStudentList(studentList);
    }
}

class StudentAdderUI extends JFrame {
    private JTextField studentNameField = new JTextField();
    private JTextField studentAgeField = new JTextField();
    private JButton addStudentBtn = new JButton("Add Student");

    private StudentAdderUIDelegate delegate;

    public StudentAdderUI(StudentAdderUIDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        addStudentBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            delegate.processStudent(studentNameField.getText(), studentAgeField.getText());
        });
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                delegate.uiClosed();
                super.windowClosed(e);
            }
        });
        // layout setup and UI show methods are omitted
    }
}

interface StudentAdderUIDelegate {
    void processStudent(String studentName, String studentAge);
    void uiClosed();
}

class StudentAdderBackend {
    private StudentAdderBackendDelegte delegate;

    public StudentAdderBackend(StudentAdderBackendDelegte delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    void processStudentList(List<Student> students) {
        // do the computation you need
        // save in DB
        // execute methods on delegate if needed
        // ...
    }
}

interface StudentAdderBackendDelegte {
    // add your methods
}
```

As you can see the Controller implements two interfaces - `StudentAdderUIDelegate` and `StudentAdderBackendDelegte`, because both UI and Backend should be able to communicate to Controller. They send data to Controller which processes and decides weather pass the data from UI to Backend or not and vice versa.
Using such delegate interfaces gives flexibility to change the UI and the Backend later. So, for example you can crate a CLI, which also will hold an instance of `delegate` object and it will process User Input from the command line and pass the input to the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you intend to do with this input() method, however in your button actionperformed code you could parse input and instantiate your Student object (assuming your Student class includes the relevant setter methods) , eg :

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(textField.getText());
        student.setName(textField_1.getText());
        ...
        ...

        // then here you could possibly add this Student object in a collection that you would have as an instance variable of your JFrame class, eg:
       studentList.add(student);
 }
```

Comment: I'm having problem with the "Collection" you said,  I don't know where should I declare the studentList, I don't want the List to be inside the Jframe because there are many functions like printing,searching, etc... to do with the List. If so how i can I add a student to THAT List inside the Jframe, should I pass the List to the Jframe as an input argrument ?